# Okay to merge included columns on otherwise identical indexes?

Tags: sql-server, index

I have two indexes that index the same field on the same table. The only difference between them is the included columns.

There's no reason I shouldn't combine the included columns and just have one index, right?

Comment: You do of course make than one index bigger than each more narrow index. This can have an impact for scan operations. Probably nothing to worry too much about, but just to point it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you should merge these indexes and only keep one,  as long as you verify that:

- Neither of them are marked as `UNIQUE` (in which case, preserve that one)
- Neither of them have a filter condition
- Neither of them are expressly referenced in an index hint

Comment: Thanks. I just combined like 5 indexes and shed close to a gigabyte of data, lol. :)